# Alternate Database to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, json

we use sql server as database with our programs but we want to have a backup for 10,15 of our critical tables so that if server with database crashes we can have those tables in a file on our local server.

I am confused on what to use to store that data . XML , JSON or any other format . I need some advice . Thank You

Comment: Why not have a second SQL Server instance on another server and replicate the data?

Comment: call your organization DBA asap. DBA knows what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, XML allows you to store data in the format of open tag/close tag, attributes, etc. Pretty much what you see on a typical HTML file it's a good example of an XML File. So, you could generate something like this for store table definitions:

```
<table name='MyTable'>
    <column type='numeric'>mycol0</column>
    <column type='varchar'>mycol1</column>
    <column type='numeric'>mycol2</column>
</table>
```

and something like this for storing records:

```
<record table='MyTable'>
     <datacolumn name='mycol0'>10</column>
     <datacolumn name='mycol1'>Hello</column>
     <datacolumn name='mycol2'>43</column>
</record>
```

On the other hand you have JSON. Unlike XML, JSON's primary used if for serializing and data  between client and server, different applications, etc. Here's  an example:

```
{"employees": [{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },  { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" },  { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ] }
```

(This example's been taken from W3School).

So, it's clear to me that if you want to export your database into a plain-text format, XML would be the best choice. You could find other alternatives, like writing your own format, but XML is the widest choice, since it's simple, easy to read and there's a lot of libraries that can help you out exporting and importing your data.

Answer (score 2):

Why re-invent something?...sql server has a built-in backup capability; run that and copy the resultant file locally. If you need to restore, it will be quick and simple as opposed to trying to piece together a database from just some of your tables that are backed up in a non-typical way.

Comment: +1 exactly - use what's available and well proven in daily use all over the world...